# Sum a Pandas DataFrame column under the ranges of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two DataFrames `DF1` and `DF2`, and I want to aggregate the values of one column in `DF1` under the date ranges of a column in `DF2`. Here is my reproducible example:

`DF1` ranges from `6/14/2013` to `7/13/2013`, and is sorted descending in time. Its columns to be aggregated are `a` and `b`. Notice, there can be multiple records for the same `date`.

```
list1 = [{'a': 5, 'date': '7/13/2013', 'b': 13},
 {'a': 4, 'date': '7/12/2013', 'b': 14},
 {'a': 7, 'date': '7/12/2013', 'b': 12},
 {'a': 2, 'date': '7/10/2013', 'b': 18},
 {'a': 9, 'date': '7/7/2013', 'b': 17},
 {'a': 6, 'date': '7/5/2013', 'b': 20},
 {'a': 8, 'date': '6/30/2013', 'b': 12},
 {'a': 5, 'date': '6/29/2013', 'b': 13},
 {'a': 3, 'date': '6/25/2013', 'b': 13},
 {'a': 4, 'date': '6/23/2013', 'b': 10},
 {'a': 1, 'date': '6/22/2013', 'b': 16},
 {'a': 6, 'date': '6/20/2013', 'b': 19},
 {'a': 7, 'date': '6/18/2013', 'b': 12},
 {'a': 9, 'date': '6/16/2013', 'b': 15}]

DF1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
```

`DF2` contains the weekly date separators, for which the `DF1` columns `a` and `b` should be aggregated.

```
list2 = [{'datesep': '6/22/2013', 'c': 32},
 {'datesep': '6/29/2013', 'c': 23},
 {'datesep': '7/6/2013', 'c': 44},
 {'datesep': '7/13/2013', 'c': 18},
 {'datesep': '7/20/2013', 'c': 51}]

DF2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)
```

What I want to do is keep `DF1.c` as is, and aggregate `DF1.a` and `DF1.b` so that the values get summed at the `DF2.datesep` separator just above their `DF1.date`. That is, the values of `DF1.a` and `DF1.b` from `6/16/2013` to `6/22/2013` (both inclusive) should be aggregated at the closest next date separator, which is `DF2.datesep=6/22/2013` row. `7/7/2013` to `7/13/2013` (both inclusive) should be aggregated at the closest next date separator, which is `DF2.datesep=7/13/2013` row etc. Therefore the result should look like (column orders don't matter):

```
       c       date a_sum  b_sum
0     32  6/22/2013    23     62
1     23  6/29/2013    12     36
2     44   7/6/2013    14     32
3     18  7/13/2013    27     74
4     51  7/20/2013     -      -
```

I did this with a loop on `list1` and `list2`, but is there a Pandas/Numpy solution that utilizes `DF1` and `DF2`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert the date strings to actual date. Then you can use a lambda to calculate a_sum and b_sum for each row. Finally combine the sum df to DF2:

```
DF1.date = pd.to_datetime(DF1.date)
DF2['end'] = pd.to_datetime(DF2.datesep)
DF2['start'] = DF2.end.shift(1).fillna(pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01'))
sums = DF2.apply(lambda x: DF1.loc[DF1.date.gt(x.start) & DF1.date.le(x.end)][['a','b']].sum(), axis=1)
sums.columns=['a_sum','b_sum']
pd.concat([DF2[['c','datesep']],sums],1)

    c   datesep a_sum   b_sum
0   32  6/22/2013   23  62
1   23  6/29/2013   12  36
2   44  7/6/2013    14  32
3   18  7/13/2013   27  74
4   51  7/20/2013   0   0
```